# Keras LSTM layers input shape

Tags: python-3.x, deep-learning, keras, lstm

I am trying to feed a sequence with 20 featuresto an LSTM network as shown in the code. But I get an error that my Input0 is incompatible with LSTM input. Not sure how to change my layer structure to fit the data.

```
def build_model(features, aux1=None, aux2=None):
# create model
features[0] = np.asarray(features[0])
main_input = Input(shape=features[0].shape, dtype='float32', name='main_input')
main_out   = LSTM(40, activation='relu')
aux1_input = Input(shape=(len(aux1[0]),),   dtype='float32', name='aux1_input')
aux1_out   = Dense(len(aux1[0]))(aux1_input)
aux2_input = Input(shape=(len(aux2[0]),),   dtype='float32', name='aux2_input')
aux2_out   = Dense(len(aux2[0]))(aux2_input)
x = concatenate([aux1_out, main_out, aux2_out])
x = Dense(64, activation='relu')(x)
x = Dropout(0.5)(x)
output = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid', name='main_output')(x)
model = Model(inputs=[aux1_input, aux2_input, main_input], outputs= [output])
return model
```

Features variable is an array of shape (1456, 20) I have 1456 days and for each day I have 20 variables.

Comment: Please show the error message. Your sequence has 20 **features**? But what is the **length** of your sequence? (How many time steps?)

Comment: ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer lstm_1: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2
is the exact error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your main_input should be of shape `(samples, timesteps, features)`
and then you should define main_input like this:

```
main_input = Input(shape=(timesteps,))  # for stateless RNN (your one)
```

or `main_input = Input(batch_shape=(batch_size, timesteps,))` for stateful RNN (not the one you are using in your example)

if your `features[0]` is a 1-dimensional array of various features (1 timestep), then you also have to reshape `features[0]` like this:

```
features[0] = np.reshape(features[0], (1, features[0].shape))
```

and then do it to `features[1]`, `features[2]` etc

or better reshape all your samples at once:

```
features = np.reshape(features, (features.shape[0], 1, features.shape[1]))
```

Comment: I changed the main input as                                                            main_input = Input(batch_shape=(batch_size, 20,), dtype='float32',     name='main_input')
main_out   = LSTM(40, activation='relu')(main_input) but I still have the error (Input 0 is incompatible with layer lstm_1: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2)

Comment: @Oğu did you make sure that your x.shape and y.shape have 3 dimensions (samples, timesteps, features) ? You have to reshape the data otherwise

Answer (score 3):

LSTM layers are designed to work with "sequences".

You say your sequence has 20 features, but how many **time steps** does it have?? Do you mean 20 time steps instead?

An LSTM layer requires input shapes such as `(BatchSize, TimeSteps, Features)`.

If it's the case that you have `1 feature` in each of the `20 time steps`, you must shape your data as:

```
inputData = someData.reshape(NumberOfSequences, 20, 1)
```

And the `Input` tensor should take this shape:

```
main_input = Input((20,1), ...) #yes, it ignores the batch size
```

Comment: How would I modify my input ("features" in this case) if I have 5 timesteps?

Comment: Reshape it as `(NumberOfSequences, 5, 20)` --- Assuming there are 20 features that vary along the 5 time steps. --- --- One thing I noticed is that you use `features[0].shape` as input shape. If `features[0]` is already shaped correctly, you should use `features[0].shape[1:]`, because the first number is the `NumberOfSequences`, which is not passed when defining layers.